# Excluding first index item from a list and bind the rest to a listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a `ObservableCollection<>` of images(byte) and title(string). I want it to bind to two different GRID: GridA and GridB. In GridA, I have an image control to which I want to bind the image in the index[0] of the collection and in GridB, an image listbox is there to which I want the remaining item from the collection i.e. excluding index[0].

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create separate properties on the ViewModel which contain what you want and bind each grid to them.
Something like:

```
public Image GridAContent
{
    get
    {
        return this.Items.First();
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Image> GridBContent
{
    get
    {
        return this.Items.Skip(1);
    }
}
```

Assuming that your current observable collection is called `Items`.